# How to add copy/paste menu in an Entery using Python/PySimpleGUI?

Tags: text, copy, clipboard, paste, pysimplegui

Dears,

How to add copy/paste menu in an Entery using Python/PySimpleGUI?
Bellow is and example where I want to add "Copy/Paste" menu for copying inputtext enteries to clipboard and paste it somewhere else :

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
[sg.Text('UserName:', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(default_text='',key='USERNAME',size=(15,1))],
[sg.Text('Password:', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(default_text='',key='PASSWORD',size=(15,1))],
[sg.Button('Exit', bind_return_key=True)],
]

window = sg.Window('Copy/Paste', layout, element_justification='c')

while True:

event, values = window.read()

if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
    break
elif event == 'Exit':
    user_text = values[0]
    print(user_text)

window.close()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dear @Jason Yang, any clue about this topic?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tkinter code required here

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

right_click_menu = ['', ['Copy', 'Paste']]

sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12), element_size=(15, 1))

layout = [
    [sg.Text('UserName:'), sg.Input(key='USERNAME', right_click_menu=right_click_menu)],
    [sg.Text('Password:'), sg.Input(key='PASSWORD', right_click_menu=right_click_menu)],
    [sg.Button('Submit')],
]

window = sg.Window('Copy/Paste', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    print(event)

    if event in ('Copy', 'Paste'):
        widget = window.find_element_with_focus().widget
        if event == 'Copy' and widget.select_present():
            text = widget.selection_get()
            window.TKroot.clipboard_clear()
            window.TKroot.clipboard_append(text)
        elif event == 'Paste':
            if widget.select_present():
                widget.delete(sg.tk.SEL_FIRST, sg.tk.SEL_LAST)
            widget.insert(sg.tk.INSERT, window.TKroot.clipboard_get())

window.close()
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason Yang for usual support

Answer (score 0):

If you use PySimpleGUI's Menu Keys, then you'll know which right-click menu is being used. I think it's possible without special tkinter code.  PySimpleGUI uses tkinter's clipboard functionality in the clipboard API calls.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

right_click_menu_user = ['', ['Copy::Username', 'Paste::Username']]
right_click_menu_password = ['', ['Copy::Password', 'Paste::Password']]

sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12), element_size=(15, 1))

layout = [[sg.Text('UserName:'), sg.Input(key='USERNAME', right_click_menu=right_click_menu_user)],
          [sg.Text('Password:'), sg.Input(key='PASSWORD', right_click_menu=right_click_menu_password)],
          [sg.Button('Submit')],]

window = sg.Window('Copy/Paste', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    if event.startswith('Copy'):
        if event.endswith('Username'):
            text = values['USERNAME']
        else:
            text = values['PASSWORD']
        sg.clipboard_set(text)
    elif event.startswith('Paste'):
        if event.endswith('Username'):
            window['USERNAME'].update(sg.clipboard_get())
        else:
            window['PASSWORD'].update(sg.clipboard_get())
window.close()
```

You can shorten the code a bit too by using ternary operator

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

right_click_menu_user = ['', ['Copy::Username', 'Paste::Username']]
right_click_menu_password = ['', ['Copy::Password', 'Paste::Password']]

sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12), element_size=(15, 1))

layout = [[sg.Text('UserName:'), sg.Input(key='USERNAME', right_click_menu=right_click_menu_user)],
          [sg.Text('Password:'), sg.Input(key='PASSWORD', right_click_menu=right_click_menu_password)],
          [sg.Button('Submit')],]

window = sg.Window('Copy/Paste', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    if event.startswith('Copy'):
        sg.clipboard_set(values['USERNAME'] if event.endswith('Username') else values['PASSWORD'])
    elif event.startswith('Paste'):
        window['USERNAME' if event.endswith('Username') else 'PASSWORD'].update(sg.clipboard_get())

window.close()
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike from PSG, Possible to add "Select all " & "Cut" option to the menu without using "tkinter" ?

Comment: Hello @Mike from PSG, any idea about this ?